# Running simulations on high performing computing cluster generates the same results

Tags: matlab, random, parallel-processing, simulation, hpc

I am performing Gillespie simulations a thousand times which take a very long time. I decided to run 10 scripts each with 100 simulations on high performing computing clusters of my school. However, once I did this and checked the results, the list of the results from the first script are the same as the second script. Meaning if I run the same scripts twice I get the exact same list of results back. Why is this happening given the fact that Gillespie simulations generate random results?

Comment: Did each of the 10 scripts get its own separate seed ?

Comment: Even if I put rng('shuffle') at the beginning the results end up the same running the same script twice

Comment: Assuming it is MATLAB, `rng('shuffle') ` results in a seed based on current time. I cannot find the time granularity. Could it be that the scripts start simultaneously ? Maybe try with different explicit seeds.

Comment: You might want to add some programming language tag (like “matlab” if applicable) to attract the appropriate sort of readership to your question.

Comment: @jpmarinier Thanks, I added a Matlab tag. I believe it doesn't really matter, I have ran the script multiple times (not at the same time) and each time the results are exactly the same. For example: 155, 45, 38, 92 and then if I run the script again I get the same numbers.